# Object reference updating, update all collections property?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

**Introduction**

I found a very weird situation, so essentially I've a collection property called `Matches` and an object property called `Match`.
The `Matches` collections contains a list of item of `Match`, like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Match> _matches = new ObservableCollection<Match>(); 
public ObservableCollection<Match> Matches
{
    get { return _matches; }
}
```

this collection is valorized when the application start, infact, the software take some data from an Internet site and then, with a scraper fill the collection with the correspond object model `Match`.

**Where the bug start**

The `Matches` collection is binded to a DataGrid. When the user click on an element (`Match`), available on the `DataGrid`, the code fire the event `SelectionChanged`, inside this event I create a copy of the `Match` clicked, so I can use this object inside all my application:

```
var match = controller.Matches.FirstOrDefault(c => c.MatchLink == ((Match)Matches.SelectedItem).MatchLink);
```

as you can see with the use of `Linq`, I check if the `Match` clicked by the user have the same link of a `Match` contained in the `Matches` collection, infact, each `Match` in the collection have a unique link like a `GUID` for example.

**The bug**

The `Match` object look like this:

```
 private Match _match;
 public Match Match
 {
    get { return _match; }
    set
    {
        _match = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

and as I said it contains the `Match` clicked by the user. This object allow me to get the data from Internet only for this `Match`, from all methods inside my app. This working pretty well. Until now.

My application allow the user to apply some filters, essentially the user press a button and then the `Match` saved is updated with the property filled by the user, for example:

```
Match.League.Rounds = availableRounds;
```

this code cause the bug, but I'll try to explain the bug better later, I need to explain a bit what happen here.
Essentially the current `Match` saved in the application should update only the own property `League.Rounds`, this property is a list of `Rounds` available for this `Match`, the structure is very simple:

```
public class Round
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the update working good but, the line `Match.League.Rounds = availableRounds;` update also all the property `League.Rounds` available in the objects collection `Matches`.

I don't understand why happen this, I've not created a reference of the object clicked:

```
var match = controller.Matches.FirstOrDefault(c => c.MatchLink == ((Match)Matches.SelectedItem).MatchLink);
```

**Practice example of what's happening**

before filters applied

```
Matches Collection
   Match.Leagues.Rounds[0] contains Id 10 and Name foo
```

after filters applied

```
Matches Collection
   Match.Leagues.Rounds[0] contains Id 11 and Name foofoo
```

but it should not be modified, only the `Match` should be modified.

but a new object. Someone could explain how to fix this? Best regards.

Comment: Match is a class in Regex.  Maybe the the two Match class are getting mixed up?

Comment: "inside this event I create a copy of the Match clicked" - why do you think that? You created reference to the object in collection.

Comment: @jdweng in this case it's not, @Evk I also tried with: `Match mtc = new Match()` and passed this new object to `Match` property, but same result

Comment: I think this might due to the behavior of [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've not created a reference of the object clicked

Yes, you have. This does *not* create a new `Match` object:

```
var match = controller.Matches.FirstOrDefault(c => c.MatchLink == ((Match)Matches.SelectedItem).MatchLink);
```

It gets a reference to the already existing `Match` object in the `Matches` collection.

If you want to create a new object, you should use the `new` operator:

```
var existing = controller.Matches.FirstOrDefault(c => c.MatchLink == ((Match)Matches.SelectedItem).MatchLink);
Match match = new Match();
//set all properties of the new object...
match.Prop1 = existing.Prop1;
```

Also note that you need to create new `Round` objects as well. You should consider implementing the `IClonable` interface.

The `FirstOrDefault()` method doesn't clone the object for you.

Comment: so the better way is to implement a class that clone the object and is property, right?

Comment: Yes. You could implement the ICloneable interface.

Comment: could you please show me a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: You need to new up the Match object itself and all child objects one way or another. There is no better way to clone the object. I showed you an example.

Comment: I've implemented the clone interface and now all working good, thanks very much, have a good day :)